# Using map, Pool and Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a `list` containing `tuples` as elements. the list looks like this:
`elements = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ...]`

There are some operations that I want to do on this list. But the number of elements in this list is huge. Hence I want to do multiprocessing. Also, the final result should be stored in another list. But I am not able to figure out how to pass the arguments. Here is my sample code:

```
class DoSomething:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self, pair, final_list):
        y = " ".join(pair)
        if y in ["a b c", " b c", "a c"]:
            final_list+=y

pairs = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
ds = DoSomething()
p =  Pool()

with Manager() as manager:
    final_list = manager.list()
    p.map(ds(..)) # I don't know how to call this now
```

How to pass the `final_list` to `ds` now?

Comment: have you tried using : pool.map(function_to_operate,list) and called function will look like this: function_to_operate(parameter) ?
do provide workable code so that we can help you with the query.

Comment: I have already provided the code. I just want to know how to call the `map` function now with my pool instance

Comment: did you tried it with above suggestion? which one is the function you're trying to call? code you provided is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to pass the `final_list` to the callable object, just declare the `final_list` inside the class or even better inside the `__init__`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


class DoSomething:
    m = Manager()
    final_list = m.list()
    def __init__(self):
    # m = Manager()
    # self.final_list = m.list()
        pass
    def __call__(self, pair):
        y = " ".join(pair)
        if y not in ["a b c", " b c", "a c"]:
            self.final_list.append(y)

pairs = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
ds = DoSomething()
p =  Pool()

p.map(ds, pairs)

print(ds.final_list)
```

Or you can use `starmap` as well to pass multiple arguments, like below

```
l = list(zip_longest(l, pairs))
p.starmap(ds, l)
```